# PHP load page only on Included page

Tags: php, redirect

I have a `process.php` page,

```
<p>This is process page</p>
```

And I have a `index.php` page:

```
<?php include_once 'process.php' ?>
```

When I type `process.php` or `index.php` in web URL both url prints the same result:  `This is process page.`

What I want is,

- I want to access this `process.php` page only when it is included or only from `index.php` page.
- When I type `process.php` then it should redirect on somewhere else or print nothing.

How can I do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so check to see if the url equals to that asked and that the file equals it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done through a variable, or a constant:

index.php

```
define('IN_APP', true);
include('process.php'); //APP will be defined
```

process.php

```
if (!defined('IN_APP')) {
    //You can also add redirects here.
    die('Do not access this script directly.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the page name of the included file vs the page the user is on... when doing it this way you don't have to add extra vars to your code.

Change process.php

```
if(basename(__FILE__, ".php") != basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php")){
    echo "<p>This is process page</p>";
}
```

Explaining the functions:

> This returns the included file name:
>
> ```
> basename(__FILE__, ".php")
> ```
>
> This returns the file name the user is on:
>
> ```
> basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

`index.php`

```
$sourcePage = __FILE__; 
include 'process.php';
```

Now on `process.php`

```
 if (isset($sourcePage)){
echo "Page is legally called from ".$sourcePage;
//or do your stuff here
}else{
die("Page was accessed directly, execution aborted.");
}
```